Dynamic schema selection in express-validator
How can I use the checkSchema function if the schema should be dependent on the body?
For example, if the Type is "A" then SomeData has to be provided in the body but if Type is anything else then this rule does not apply.
const schemaForAllTypes = {
    Type: {
        in: 'body',
        notEmpty: {
            errorMessage: "'Type' has to be provided in body"
        }
    }
};

const schemaForTypeA = {
    Type: {
        in: 'body',
        notEmpty: {
            errorMessage: "'Type' has to be provided in body"
        }
    },
    SomeData: {
        in: 'body',
        notEmpty: {
            errorMessage: "'SomeData' has to be provided in body"
        },
        isJSON: {
            errorMessage: "'SomeData' has to be JSON"
        }
    }
};




Since checkSchema(...) returns an object with all the validation rules (as functions) and run function, one can achieve the dynamic schema validation as follows:
const express = require('express');
const { checkSchema } = require('express-validator');
const router = express.Router();

const BaseSchema = {
    Type: {
        in: 'body',
        notEmpty: {
            errorMessage: "'Type' has to be provided in body"
        }
    }
};
const validateSchemaDynamically = () => async (req, res, next) => {
    // to choose the schema dynamically, we need the type
    const { Type } = req.body;
    switch (Type) {
        case 'A':
            const schema = {
                ...BaseSchema,
                SomeData: {
                    in: 'body',
                    notEmpty: {
                        errorMessage: "'SomeData' has to be provided in body"
                    },
                    isJSON: {
                        errorMessage: "'SomeData' has to be JSON"
                    }
                }
            };

            await checkSchema(schema).run(req);
            return next();
        default:
            await checkSchema(BaseSchema).run(req);
            return next();
    }
};

router.post(
    '/my-endpoint',
    validateSchemaDynamically(),
    handleValidationErrors(), // middleware to check (and handle) validation errors
    async (req, res) => {
        console.log('Business logic here...');
        return res.status(202).send();
    }
);


PS: Please feel free to provide feedback. Answer the question if you know a better way so that we all can learn.
Especially, I would appreciate if experts can answer whether this is the right way or not. I wrote some unit test and it seems to do the job, but maybe there is something I am missing?
